# Is it true for $a,b,c$ positive reals that $\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+2b^2}}+\frac{b}{\sqrt{b^2+2c^2}}+\frac{c}{\sqrt{c^2+2a^2}} \ge \sqrt3$

Tags: inequality

Is it true for $a,b,c$ positive reals that $$\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+2b^2}}+\frac{b}{\sqrt{b^2+2c^2}}+\frac{c}{\sqrt{c^2+2a^2}} \ge \sqrt3$$

My thoughts:

The LHS is equal to $$\frac{a^2}{\sqrt{a^2(a^2+2b^2)}}+\frac{b^2}{\sqrt{b^2(b^2+2c^2)}}+\frac{c^2}{\sqrt{c^2(c^2+2a^2)}} \stackrel{AM-GM}{\ge} \frac{a^2}{a^2+b^2}+\frac{b^2}{b^2+c^2}+\frac{c^2}{c^2+a^2} $$

So I am left to prove  that $\dfrac{a^2}{a^2+b^2}+\dfrac{b^2}{b^2+c^2}+\dfrac{c^2}{c^2+a^2} \ge \sqrt3$ but I don't know how to proceed...

I also tried to prove the very first inequality using Holder's inequality but I end up wanting to prove that $(a+b+c)^3 \ge 3a(a^2+2b^2)+3b(b^2+2c^2)+3c(c^2+2a^2)$ but it doesn't seem to be correct.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something?  It doesn't seem to be true for $a = b = c = 1$, where the LHS is equal to $\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: I edited the problem. The RHS was $\sqrt3$ actually

Comment: Try $a=1$, $b=2$, $c=1$.

Comment: The inequality clearly does not hold true for all positive reals... Please correct or close the question.